# Can Babel Apply to Selected Files in Webpack Config?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Here is my webpack.config (using webpack 3) below

I have several `.js` files in `entry`.

I'd like to find a way to transpile *select* `.js` files through babel while excluding others.

I found a way to include all the `.js` files in the js/ directory through babel.. But how can I exclude the `.js` files in js/vendor?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: {
    dataviz : '../js/entry-dataviz.js',
    template : '../js/entry-viz-template.js',
    abc : '../js/entry-viz-abc.js',
    sample: '../js/sample.js',
    vendor: [
      '../js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
      '../js/vendor/history.js',
      '../js/vendor/history.adapter.jquery.js'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '../js'), <-- including everything in js/directory
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: 'es2015'}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

[`include`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) can accept a function:

```js
include: function (modulePath) {
  // inside `js` folder but not `js/vendor`
  return true;
}
```